# Sinatra does not support multiple lines?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

For the following code, why does only "World" gets printed

```
get '/' do
 "Hello"
 "World"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomas correctly answered your question, but one way to do what I think you're meaning to do (output multiple lines), you could use:

```
get '/' do
  output =<<EOS
Hello
World
EOS
  output
end
```

Answer (score 12):

This has nothing to do with sinatra itself. It just uses the return value of the block and in ruby the return value is the last evaluated expression, which in your case is "World". This might work for you:

```
get '/' do
  r = "Hello"
  r += "World"
end
```

In this case you add as many string values to `r` as you want and the last expression would return the complete string "HelloWorld".

Comment: Still, using + generates a new string object every time. Try using << instead.

Answer (score 4):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I do believe in plain ruby, the last line evaluated is what gets returned.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a line break char to separate lines..

```
get '/' do
"Hello\nWorld"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse your controller with your view.

What you're probably looking for is this:

```
get '/' do
  haml :hello_world
end
```

And then in `views/hello_world.haml`:

```
Hello
World
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Matt.

If you want you can use that method with one file too.

```
 get '/' do
   erb :hello_world
 end
```

__END__

@@hello_world
hello
world

I just use puts inside my controller to get some debug printed to STDOUT.